# Changing the DOM Insert Location of the Drift Widget

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, drift

I have a Vue.js application that uses the Drift chat tool (see: https://www.drift.com/). The problem I am having is that the Drift Javascript snippet inserts the `#drift-widget-container` at the bottom of my `body` tag i.e. outside of my `#app` container.

As a result, this means that I cannot use any of my custom Vue plugins to manipulate the position and visibility of the widget. For example, reveal on scroll...

My question, quite simply, is anyone aware of a way in which I can tell Drift to insert the widget into a target DOM node instead of at the end of the `body` tag?

I appreciate that there is an easy, but dirty, fix available but I would ideally like to avoid doing this:

- Upon initialising Vue, using `document.getElementById`, move the widget into my `#app` container - **Update** - This does not work as moving it in the DOM messes up the Widget tracking.

### Drift Code

This is the code that Drift request you to include in the head of the site. From what I can see, it simply loads their necessary JS code, and then initiates the chat widget.

```
"use strict";

!function() {
    var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
    if (!t.init) {
        if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
        t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ],
            t.factory = function(e) {
                return function() {
                    var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                    return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
                };
            }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
            t[e] = t.factory(e);
        }), t.load = function(t) {
            var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
            o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
            var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
        };
    }
}();
drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';
drift.load('XXX'); // This is what initiates the widget
```

The `drift.load` method (not to be confused with the `load` function, this loads their JS) is what initiates the widget and places it into the DOM. I have attempted to reverse engineer their code as the API documentation is pitiful, and from what I can see, there is no option to specify a different element to be appended.

You can see their full code [here](https://js.driftt.com/include/1560532200000/max9vseayf9p.js) - (you will need to 'beautify' it as it is minified)

From what I have found, I think it is very unlikely that this is actually possible. The only solution is to use `document.getElementById` from within my Vue component, and then just manipulate the styles from there. It's not the end of the world, but it isn't particularly clean...

Comment: As a disclaimer, I am not familiar with Drift... Now that that's out of the way... Does Drift automatically add the widget to the bottom of the body? Are you not able to override the "Drift mount `div`"?  Would you mind posting some of the Drift code?

Comment: @MattOestreich - nor am I, I only started looking at their API a few hours ago... See my updated question :-D